# Is "User.Identity.Name" safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, forms-authentication

I wonder if I can use *User.Identity.Name* to query data from my db.
Ex:

```
UsersBLL.GetPersonalInformation(string username)
```

Would passing the value of *User.Identity.Name* to this method is a good idea?
Can the value of User.Identity.Name be hijacked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be hijacked? Yes, for example via session hijacking due to [insufficient transport layer protection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/11/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-9.html) (working example of this in that link) but this isn't a risk with the membership provider implementation per se.

Rather than passing the user name around, I'd stick to the ID:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();
var userId = (Guid?)user.ProviderUserKey;
```

I assume any tables dependent on the aspnet_Users user table (assuming, again, you're using the default membership provider), are using the ID as the foreign key and not the username. At least I hope that's the case!

Comment: I'm not using the membership system, just my own db, and yes I'm using the ID as the foreign key. but I'm using the username for my methods to avoid another roundtrip to the db, is this a bad practice? should I pass the userid instead? should I just query the userid and cache it for later use?

Comment: It's an internal implementation, you're not exposing it in a fashion which facilitates hijacking and so long as you're still using proper access controls, it should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

User.Identity.Name is as safe as any other means.  Is it possible to hijack it?  Maybe, if you're not using ssl and you're not encrypting your authentication mechanism, but if you are using SSL and using encrypted FormsAuthentication or Windows Authentication you should be fine.

Basically, if you're following good security practices, it should be perfectly safe.  At least no less safe than any other way of identifying the user.

EDIT:

This assumes that you aren't keying your tables on username, but rather by the Membership userid, and your code just looks up the userid in the membership tables by name.

If you are keying your tables on username, then there are a number of security concerns to take into account.  One of which is what Henk mentions in his answer.  If you don't allow usernames to change, or be reused then it's not an issue.

Comment: Add it shields your application from the underlying authentication mechanism. For example, you could switch from Kerberos to 2-Way SSL or Claims-from-hell, and your application would not need much change.